# Pulling and reinserting to database removes a part of the values

Tags: php, sql, pdo, insert

I am pulling information out of the database and putting it into a select field. In the select field, it appears whole, but upon reinsertion to the database, any of the words after the initial space are stripped.

Here is my code:

```
<?
require_once('./inc/glob_head.php');
if (isset($_POST['submitNewOther']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    try {
        $checkDB = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM mainSite_others WHERE forGame=:fg AND otherType=:ot AND otherName=:otn');
        $addToDB = $database->prepare('INSERT INTO mainSite_others(forGame,otherType,otherName,otherDesc,otherCost,membeOnly,otherPageContent) VALUES (:fg,:ot,:otn,:od,:oc,:mo,:opc)');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        exit();
    }
    $checkDB->execute(array(':fg'=>$_POST['forGame'],':ot'=>$_POST['otherType'],':otn'=>$_POST['otherName']));
    if ($checkDB->rowCount() == 0) {
        try {
            $addToDB->execute(array(':fg'=>$_POST['forGame'],':ot'=>$_POST['otherType'],':otn'=>$_POST['otherName'],':od'=>$_POST['otherDesc'],':oc'=>$_POST['otherCost'],':mo'=>$_POST['membeOnly'],':opc'=>$_POST['otherPageContent']));
            redir('addOther.php?action=success');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        echo "Other already in database";
    }
} elseif (isset($_GET) && $_GET['action'] == 'success') {
?>
    <h2>"Other" added to database.</h2>
    <h4><a href='addOther.php'>Add another</a> or choose something new to do.</h4>
<?
} else {
?>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend><h2>Add other</h2></legend>
                            <form name='addOther' id='addOther' method='POST'>
                                <select name='forGame'>
                                    <?
                                    try {
                                        $listOfGames = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM mainSite_games');
                                        $listOfGames->execute();
                                        $games = $listOfGames->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                        foreach ($games as $game) {
                                            print '<option value='.$game['gameName'].'>'.$game['gameName'].'</option>';
                                        }
                                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                        error_log($e->getMessage());
                                        exit();
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select><br />
                                <select name='otherType'>
                                    <option value='Item'>Item</option>
                                    <option value='Place'>Place</option>
                                    <option value='Character'>Character</option>
                                </select><br />
                                <input type='text' name='otherName' placeholder='Other name' required /><br />
                                <input type='text' name='otherDesc' placeholder='Other examine (or NA)' required /><br />
                                <input type='text' name='otherCost' placeholder='Other cost (price/NA)' required /><br />
                                <input type='text' name='membeOnly' placeholder='Members Only (Yes/No)' required /><br />
                                <textarea name="otherPageContent" class="span12" rows="10" placeholder="Other page content" required></textarea><br />
                                <input type='submit' name='submitNewOther' class='btn btn-primary' /><br />
                            </form>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
<?
}
$database = null;
?>
```

The bottom (the plain html part) is where it pulls out of the database -- the first select is where it is put. It is whole when viewed:

[image: whole information]

Now, when this form is submitted, it enters into the database successfully, but appears as this -- therefore breaking my website (now allowing the user's to see this games content because the game's database/quests do not exist as far as it knows (it's checking for the whole name). This is what it looks like in the SQL admin:

[image: corrupt]

RuneScape is fine (because there aren't spaces I'm guessing?) however Carnage is supposed to be Carnage Racing.

Are there problems with my code causing this? This isn't the only page it's happening on, but I suppose if I find the source I can fix it on all pages.

**redir() is a custom function that uses JS to redir so that I don't have to play around with headers**

Comment: Solved - fixed via the usage of urlencode.

Comment: Better post an answer to your own question with an explanation so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by encasing the problem variable in the PHP urlencode function. What I took away from this is that select tags, when being inserted into the database, most likely have their values stripped of spaces (and therefore anything after the primary space), so when I need to call the variable, I will have to encase it in the PHP urldecode function.